# Code Hyperlink in Excel for upload to MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, hyperlink

I want to code an image numer in my excel database with the hyperlink to that actual image on the webpage where it can be found.  My Excel file is then Uploaded into ACCESS for upload to my MySql database on my server by using ODBC to upload the Access file.

How do I code the hyperlink in Excel so that it will appear as clickable in the MySql database on my server so others can click that link?

Comment: Hi Laura, how are you ultimately intending to display the data in your database that contains the link?

Comment: If it's a URL then you should load the URL - it's up to your display (web application?) to render the URL as an image.

Comment: I have an online database which is a transcription of documents for births, marriages and deaths from a town in Sicily.  The documents are now online and accessible bUT they are very hard to find as they do not always follow in order so my thought was to hyperlink to the actual document to make it easier to find

Comment: I don't want to display the image.  I want the image number to be clickable to take the user to the image that is displayed on the website where it is located.  The images are NOT on my website and I cannot put them on my website

Comment: I have tried to make the cell that contains the link as hypertext but when I import the file into Access to the upload to PhpMyAdmin on my website through ODBC, the link is not clickable

Comment: Actually, when I import the Excel file into Access, the link disappears in Access.  I can click on it in Excel and it will take me directly to the webpage where the image is located but you can't do that from in Access so the link doesn't upload to phpMyAdmin when I do the ODBC.  Is there an easy way to upload from the Excel file directly to phpmyAdmin than going through this process and will that allow the link to upload as well